# Overloaded method filter

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have an exercise where I have to find first >=0 element which IS NOT in the Set.
My plan was to firstly: `filter` the negative numbers from the set, then to make pairs by `sliding`, then to add the `difference` to the tuple (if it's 1, I know that there isn't any Int element which is not in Set between them). Then I wanted to filter out ones, that difference is not 1 - so I know that the element that I'm searching for is e.g.

Having `Set(-3,0,1,2,4)`, I have tuples `(0,1),(1,2),(2,4)` --> filtered out in the end is only `(2,4, 2 (difference))`, so my element is `2+1 = 3`.

When I'm trying to `filter` out the ones with the difference != 1, it says that it couldn't resolve overloaded method `filter`

```
def minNotContained(set: Set[Int]): Int = {
   val positive = set.filter(_ >= 0)
   val pairs = positive.sliding(2).toList.map(_.toList)
   val pairsWithDifference = pairs.map{case List(a: Int,b: Int) => List((a,b,b-a))}.filter((x,y,z) => z!=1)
  

 }
```

Comment: Your code would become much easier if it worked directly with tuples instead of wrapping them in a List. 
Also note that iterating over the elements in the set is not necessarily sorted

Comment: In my exercise I assume that the set is sorted. So how could I work with tuples? I don't really know why it (`filter`) doesn't want to work when I write `(x,y,z) => z != 1 ` .....

Comment: your filter would work if you used `.filter { case List((x,y,z)) => z!=1}`

Comment: ok, it's impossible to do it like this - it makes in `val pairs` HashSet which doesn't take elements one by one, but combines then, e.g. (0,4) instead of (0,1)

Answer (score 1):

Use `dropWhile()` as your filter.

```
val setOfInts = Set(....)
val result = LazyList.from(0).dropWhile(setOfInts).head
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it like this, but it's not the case.... I need to do that exercise using operations on collections, sorry for answering my question, but I wanted to my solution to be visible better.

```
def minNotContained(set: Set[Int]): Int = {
    val positive = set.filter(_ >= 0)
    @tailrec def isInSet(collection: Set[Int], number: Int): Int = {
      if (collection.contains(number)) isInSet(collection, number+1) else number
    }
    isInSet(set,0)
    
  }
  println(minNotContained(Set(-3,0,1,2,4,5,6)))
```